# Copying a Listbox

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, copy

I have a Form that has Listboxes that return values from different queries for agent. I have made a copy button to copy this information to a clipboard i have hide in the form. However the Copy button will not copy the listbox.

```
Private Sub cpyTLES_Click()

Me.lstClipboard = "Team Lead Error Scorecard" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Team Lead:" & Me.Team_Lead & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Total of Cases Created:" & Me.List14 & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Number Of Errors:" & Me.List18 & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Percent Of Errors:" & Me.List16 & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Error Types:" & Me.List56 & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
Me.lstClipboard.Visible = True
Me.lstClipboard.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
Me.List56.SetFocus
Me.lstClipboard.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I think your clipboard should rather be a **textbox** than a listbox, if you want to put multi-line strings into it.

Comment: My Clipboard is a Textbox